# How to force open links in Chrome not download them?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I want to open a link that is .psd format with Photoshop when clicked in Google Chrome like Firefox that asks me to open or download the file. But Google Chrome downloads the file automatically.
How can I force to open the links in Chrome without downloading? The links are for local files.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To make certain file types OPEN on your computer, instead of Chrome Downloading...

You have to download the file type once, then right after that download, look at the status bar at the bottom of the browser.  Click the arrow next to that file and choose "always open files of this type".    DONE.

Now the file type will always OPEN using your default program.

To reset this feature, go to Settings / Advance Settings and under the "Download.." section, there's a button to reset 'all' Auto Downloads

Hope this helps..  :-)

Visual Instructions found here:

http://www.presentermedia.com/blog/2013/10/my-file-automatically-opens-instead-of-saving-with-chrome/

Comment: This won't prevent you from downloading the file. It simply opens automatically a downloaded file.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question because the question wants to prevent downloading. This does not prevent downloading, it just automatically opens the downloaded file.

Comment: On Windows, this opens the file in Notepad. Would like to know how to read   "any.log"  from Chrome directly (as seen for "any.txt" files)

Comment: I agree with Larry. This does not prevent downloading and so does not answer the question. Guest's answer below does.

Answer (score 40):

Great question.

It can be achieved via an extension:

- For Chrome, load [undisposition](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/undisposition?hl=en)
- If the file loading is ASCII then colour coding may be desirable, that can be done via 
  the [Syntaxtic](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Syntaxtic!?hl=en) extension
- btw, for Firefox load the [InlineDisposition](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inlinedisposition-reloaded) add-on

Comment: This is the most "correct" answer, as it's likely often caused by  `content-disposition: attachment`. However, in my case, though I think the problem was a `content-type: application/octet-string`, neither this nor any of the other header-rewriter extensions I found for Chrome could solve the problem. :/

Comment: Wow, Undisposition is really great! Looking for this for years, you're my savior! ;)

Comment: (For "undisposition") This is perfect, exactly what I needed for those pages forcing links to be downloaded instead of viewed in a new tab!
Works perfectly (Using this in Edge btw) just like I expected!

Answer (score 9):

Google, as of now, cannot open w/out saving. As a workaround, I use IE Tab from the Chrome Store. It is an extension that runs IE - which does allow opening w/ out saving- inside of the Chrome browser application.

Not the best solution, but it's an effective "patch" for now.

Comment: No browser can open files without saving; that's basic computing. It's just that some browsers delete it for you once you've used it.

Comment: "No browser can open files without saving" That's incorrect. A browser should be able to open the file without saving if the file is already saved as in the case of this question - "The links are for local files."

Comment: @forresthopkinsa `without saving; that's basic computing`, someones forgetting about memory-mapping, piping/streams, shared-buffers; literally any of the things even more basic than files. It's probably true *browsers* always save to %tmp%, but that's probably more for compatibility with the majority of programs someone might want to open the data with. It'd be a mistake to assume that is the case for all programs (that send or receive the file data) or declare it as a core truth of computing. You could definitely 'download' any file straight to stdin of VIM, for example, no disk save at all.

Comment: You are technically correct -- the best kind of correct. I don't think streaming/etc applies here though

Comment: @forresthopkinsa actually there is a HUGE use case where memory storage is relevant in *browsers* specifically. Privacy mode.

Comment: @Shiv Are you suggesting that an incognito browser would load a remote file into memory rather than disk in order to open it with another program?

Comment: @forresthopkinsa unfortunately I doubt 3rd party programs can take memory handles. Chrome displaying files in browser certainly could do in-memory if they wanted to do incog properly. I don't know specifically if they do that though.

Answer (score 3):

Just found your question whilst trying to solve another problem I'm having, you will find that currently Google isn't able to perform a temporary download so therefore you have to download instead.

See: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Drge_Zrwg-c

Answer (score 2):

I think the question was about to open a local file directly instead of downloading a local file to the download folder and open the file in the download folder, which seems not possible in Chrome, except some add-on mentioned above.

My workaround would be to right click -> Copy the link location
Windows + R and paste the link there and Enter
It will go to the file directly.

Answer (score 2):

To open docs automatically in Chrome without them being saved;

1. Go to the the three vertical dots on your top far right corner in Chrome.
2. Scroll down to Settings and click.
3. Scroll down to Show advance settings...
4. Scroll down to Downloads under Download location: click the Change button and chose tmp folder. Then just close the screen.
5. Click on any attachments and a small box to the left will appear, it should automatically open if you click on it.
6. When the bottom left box appears it will contain an arrow; click on it and choose the option "Always open files of this type".  Going forward it will open the file instantly instead of the small box appearing to the left and you having to click on it to open.  You will have to do it just once for various files such PDF, Excel 2010, Excel 2013 Word, ect.

Comment: I was thinking about the same method :) But I can't decide which `tmp` folder to use. It's not `C:\Windows\Temp` we are talking about, right? Can you tell which one to use?

Comment: This does not open the file /without downloading/.

Comment: As of July 2023, Advanced settings is gone. However, step 6 is still valid--you click on the file, then click the blue arrow in the upper-right of Chrome (which points to the download folder), then RIGHT click the file in the list, and select "Always open files of this type". It's true that the file downloads, so you need to clear that folder periodically, but this method will at least open the file automatically for you (like if it's an *.wav file, it'll start playing in Windows Media Player or QuickTime immediately).

Answer (score 0):

The response from Backend side may returns `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/json`. So it forces to download file.

Contact with backend team to check that.

Comment: Backend is irrelevant to the question, which clearly states, "The links are for local files."