# Open Link To Filein Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angular, file

I Would like to create an HTML page
With links to various files (Excel, Word, etc.)
The links are to files that already exist physically.
And my goal is to open them, at their location, with the click of a button.
(For example, if I have a Word file on a network drive, clicking on it will open MICROSOFT OFFICE WORD, with the appropriate file, from the relevant location).
How can this be done with chrome?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force open links in Chrome not download them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952514/how-to-force-open-links-in-chrome-not-download-them)

Comment: it's not help me. I need to open files in their locations (and not download and then open it/ or not).

Comment: Yep, that link suggests that it's not possible.